# postgres full text search add period to parser

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgres full text search. I want to add period (.) to the list of parser by which words should be split. right now Hello world is split into Hello and world, but hello.world is not split at all.

Does anyone know how to add period (.) to the default parser list.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the only way to do this it to propgramatically update the row by splitting based on .

Comment: I have a similar problem. Are you sure this is the only way? Have you tried to implement your own parser? According to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/textsearch-intro.html#TEXTSEARCH-INTRO-CONFIGURATIONS) it seems to be possible to develop one's own parser, although I have no clue on where to begin. (that's what I'm currently for. If you have an idea about that, I'd be glad to hear it)